# Como ocultar datos de un select si ya se utilizo

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

tengo la siguiente duda...

Yo tengo una consulta donde obtengo lo que es un: **"Id"** y **"Hora"** y eso lo desplego en un select y despues creo un registro, lo que quiero lograr es que cuando ya este utilizada una hora o "Valor" de la consulta que traigo en ese select ya no me aparezca.

**Codigo:**

```
<select name="psb_hr" id="psb_hr" class="form-control" onchange='cambioOpciones();' required/>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
    <?php
    while ($rowss = $QueryResultHours->fetch_assoc()){
     printf ("<option value=".$rowss["id_desc"].">".$rowss["description"]."</option>");
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que hago mi registro queda el siguiente **resultado**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es que al volver agregar otro registro mi select ya no aparezca la opcion de la hora que tengo dada de alta ya en mis registros, ahorita se que esto es imposible por que lo estoy obteniendo de la base de datos, pero de que manera podria hacerlo?

Comment: Agrega un listener onChange al select o un botón para enviar de regreso la información con el registro seleccionado previamente, después de que te aseguras de que ya lo marcaste como no disponible, vuelves a hacer la consulta pero filtrando aquellos que ya no están disponibles, entonces limpias el select y lo populas con la nueva información.

Comment: En la consulta tendrías que hacer un [LEFT JOIN](https://programacionymas.com/blog/como-funciona-inner-left-right-full-join) de la otra tabla y, si los campos no tienen valor nulo, quiere decir que ese horario ya está en uso. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar la consulta y estructura de las dos tablas.